# Check condition only display and dynamically listview all items with difference height

Tags: android, listview

**1.Check condition only display**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, parent,
                false);     
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.image_alllatestnewstitle);
    imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    TextView titletext = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle);
    TextView categorytext = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.text_newscategorytitle);
    TextView datetext = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_newsdate);

    if (!imagepath[position].toString().equals("no picture")) {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagepath[position], imageview);
        imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
        titletext.setWidth(460 - imageview.getWidth() - 5); <-- this line   
    } else {
        imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
    titletext.setText(title[position].toString());
    categorytext.setText(category[position].toString());
    datetext.setText(date[position].toString());

    return vi;
}
```

The statement cannot be check when first view of the list and causing the textview stack with imageview. After scroll one or more times it only move to left.

How to go in this statement before display it?

**2. set all items' height in listview programmatically base on condition**

```
RelativeLayout childlayout = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_childlist);
```

This is the layout for an item.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_childlist"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/list_bg"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_alllatestnewstitle"
        android:layout_width="140px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
....
</RelativeLayout>
```

For example, one of the item took 80px to display but the other items only took 40px. However, the other items will not wrap to 40px and wrap to 80px and make all the items has same height.

How to set the height for all items with difference height?

Comment: see `@superM's` answer, and note, that `View.INVISIBLE` still keeps a "placeholder" there, so the layout won't be smaller. On the other hand, `View.GONE` offers you the aspect you want. If dealing with complex layouts, and if you use them as item renderers, you should consider creating your own `View` extension class for them, and take a look at states and state drawables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

`INVISIBLE` only hides the view while `GONE` 'removes' it

Comment: it is still same, still "eat" the space

Comment: i try set the imageview height to 30, it also same like 80

Comment: Could you please add the xml part where your textview is?

Comment: nevermind, my boss accepted my current height, however first problem is the mainly now, i got no idea why the `if-else` condition only work after scroll the list view

Comment: I could help you build your xml so that there would be no such problems. If you want that, I could add it to my answer

Comment: finally i can check the condition, but anyway thanks for answering me